# SIGHASH_SINGLE vbuterin/pybitcointools

Tags: script, python, sighash-flags, pybitcointools

Checking the implementation of Buterin's bitcoin tools I've noticed something strange. According to [the Bitcoin developers guide](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#signature-hash-types), sighash_single signs only the outputs that match the input where the scriptSig is going to be placed, that is, input `i` should sign only output `i`. However, [the code](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/blob/6db88d846d3dd0414f9064febd98d2553e14f953/bitcoin/transaction.py#L139) is always signing the current input with the last output of the transaction.

Is it a workaround to deal with a non-matching number of inputs and outputs, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone struggles with the same issue, the code was actually incorrect. [Pull request #163](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/pull/163) fixes the issue.

[Here](https://github.com/sr-gi/bitcoin_tools/blob/dev/bitcoin_tools/transaction.py#L381-L444) you can also see an equivalent solution properly commented and cited.